# Community funding ideas

Tags: small-communities, rules-and-policies, new-members, physical-communities

I am new to this so I appreciate your your time and knowledge as i get use to using this forum.  I was wondering if anyone has any experience or ideas on how to create a community find in order to fund Community projects?

Comment: Welcome to Community Building.  Could you [edit] in some details?  How much money are you trying to raise?  Is it for specific projects or are you planning for future needs?  How large is your community?  How tightly-knit is it already -- is this a neighborhood where nobody knows each others' names, a community where everybody gets together weekly for some purpose, something else?  All of these factors will affect how you go about beginning a fundraising effort.

Comment: And check your language/spelling please. I guess *find* = *fund* but then it says *creating a fund in order to fund* ;-)